# Value Stored to during its initialization is never read

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
    float latitude = [((IPADAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).detailViewController.userStoreInfoObj.StoreLatitude floatValue];
    float longitude = [((IPADAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).detailViewController.userStoreInfoObj.StoreLongitude floatValue];

    NSString *strAddress = [((IPADAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).detailViewController.userStoreInfoObj StoreAddress];
    NSString *strCountry= [((IPADAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).detailViewController.userStoreInfoObj StoreCounty];
    NSString *strCode = [((IPADAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).detailViewController.userStoreInfoObj StoreZip];

    if(storeData)
    {
        latitude  = [storeInfoObj.StoreLatitude floatValue];
        longitude = [storeInfoObj.StoreLongitude floatValue];


        strAddress = [storeInfoObj StoreAddress];
        strCountry = [storeInfoObj StoreCounty];
        strCode =    [storeInfoObj StoreZip];

    }
```

Value stored to latitude during its initialization is never read.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

What can I do to fix this? Please help me out [I try my luck].

@ Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there mission code, another place where is is set or is storeData always true?  Run Analyzer and click on the warning to see the path of execution that causes the error.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by is never read? Do you mean that when you try to read this variable later on, the initial value you set does not appear to have been set properly?

Comment: @ Madhumal Gunetileke Actually iam running application in build And Analyzing so i found this warning in my application.  so i want my application with zero warning and zero potential leak's for my project...

Comment: Is this the entire method? If you never use latitude other than to assign it within that method then that is why you are getting that warning/analyzer result.

Answer (score 0):

one example: the static analyzer has likely detected that `storeData` will always evaluate to true:

```
StoreData * storeData = thing.storeData;
if (!storeData) {
/* get out of here!!! */
    return;
}

IPADAppDelegate * appDelegate = (IPADAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UserStoreInfoObj * userStoreInfoObj = appDelegate.detailViewController.userStoreInfoObj;

float latitude = [userStoreInfoObj.StoreLatitude floatValue];
float longitude = [userStoreInfoObj.StoreLongitude floatValue];

NSString *strAddress = [userStoreInfoObj StoreAddress];
NSString *strCountry= [userStoreInfoObj StoreCounty];
NSString *strCode = [userStoreInfoObj StoreZip];


if (storeData) << would be redundant and always true
{
    latitude = [storeInfoObj.StoreLatitude floatValue]; << why not initialize latitude using this value???
    longitude = [storeInfoObj.StoreLongitude floatValue];

    strAddress = [storeInfoObj StoreAddress];
    strCountry = [storeInfoObj StoreCounty];
    strCode = [storeInfoObj StoreZip];

}
```

but you can significantly reduce the complexity of this program (to read, maintain, and execute) by using something like this:

```
UserStoreInfoObj * storeInfo = nil;
if (storeData) storeInfo = storeInfoObj;
else storeInfo = ((IPADAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).detailViewController.userStoreInfoObj;

float latitude = [storeInfo.StoreLatitude floatValue];
float longitude = [storeInfo.StoreLongitude floatValue];

NSString *strAddress = [storeInfo StoreAddress];
NSString *strCountry= [storeInfo StoreCounty];
NSString *strCode = [storeInfo StoreZip];
```